# Creating variable without defining the variables type class yet

Tags: c++, oop, variables

```cpp
class Component {
    public:
        Entity *parent = nullptr;
};

class Entity {
    public:
        Component components[25];
};
```

I am trying to create an entity component system, and above I have an issue. In the component class I am creating a pointer variable with the datatype being the "Entity" class, even though that gets defined later. Is there a way I can do this without an error occurring?

I tried using `auto *parent = nullptr;` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Use a forward declaration of `Entity` before `class Component`.  It looks like: `class Entity;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare Entity as a class, so the compiler knows what type this is.

```cpp
    class Entity;
```

Usually you would put these sorts of forward declarations in a generic header file, then define each class completely in its own Classname.cpp file.